# No such method error akka.util.Helpers$.toRootLowerCase(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: scala, rest, maven, akka

I am trying to run the following program

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{ContentTypes, HttpEntity}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives
import akka.io.IO
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await


trait JsonSupport extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val itemFormat = jsonFormat2(Item)
}


final case class Item(name: String, id: Long)

object Main extends App with RestInterface {


  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  val host = config.getString("http.host")
  val port = config.getInt("http.port")


  implicit val system = ActorSystem("My-ActorSystem")
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  //implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)

  val api = routes

  Http().bindAndHandle(api, host, port) map {
    binding => println(s"The binding local address is ${binding.localAddress}")
  }
  //  recover
  //    { case ex => println(s"some shit occurred and it is"+ex.getMessage) }


  //  sys.addShutdownHook {
  //    system.log.info("Shutting down Spray HTTP in 10 seconds...")
  //    // NOTE(soakley): We are waiting to unbind to allow the VIP time to query healthcheck status.
  //    Thread.sleep(10000)
  //    system.log.info("Shutting down Spray HTTP and allowing 10 seconds for connections to drain...")
  //    val unbindFuture =  Http.unbind(10.seconds)
  //
  //    Await.ready(unbindFuture, 10.seconds)
  //  }



}



case class Stringer(str1 : String, str2 : String, str3 : String)


trait RestInterface extends Resource {

  val routes = questionroutes ~ mydirectiveroute01 ~ mydirectiveroute02

}

trait Resource extends QuestionResource with mydirective01 with mydirective02

trait QuestionResource {
  val questionroutes = {
    path("hi") {
      get {

        val stringer_instance = Stringer("questionairre created","whatever","whatever-whatever")

        complete(ToResponseMarshallable(stringer_instance.toString()))
      }
    }
  }
}


trait mydirective01 extends BasicDirectives {

  val getandputdirective = get | put

  val mydirectiveroute01 = {



    path("customhi" / IntNumber) {
      passednumber1 => {

        path(IntNumber) {

          passednumber2 => {

            getandputdirective {
              ctx =>
                ctx.complete("Testing get and put directive" + s"The passed string is " + passednumber2 + passednumber1)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }
}


trait mydirective02 extends BasicDirectives with JsonSupport {

  val mydirectiveroute02 =
    path("hello") {
      get {
        complete(HttpEntity(
          ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
          "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
      }
    } ~
      path("randomitem") {
        get {
          // will marshal Item to JSON
          complete(Item("thing", 42))
        }
      } ~
      path("saveitem") {
        post {
          // will unmarshal JSON to Item
          entity(as[Item]) { item =>
            println(s"Server saw Item : $item")
            complete(item)
          }
        }
      }
}
```

But I get the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.util.Helpers$.toRootLowerCase(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

The error seems to be because of this line

> implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

May I know where I am going wrong. I have identical pom.xml file and the program in another module and it seems to run fine. I dont understand where I am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: which jdk and scala versions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I get errors like that when something that should have been re-compiled has not been re-compiled.   clean" followed by "compile" in sbt resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the  conflict in dependencies make sure you are using same version for all the related packages you are importing.

```
example:
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-http-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

2.11 make sure you have other dependencies with same version
then make a clean build.

Answer (score 0):

Your project dependencies have conflicting versions. The version that has that function gets discarded, and the other version included in the jar (or classpath - depending on how you execute).
Please provide your dependencies file (i.e. `sbt.build` or `gradle.build` etc.)